# Write a program that simulates flipping a coin repeatedly and continues until three consecutive heads are tossed, in C++

Tags: c++

Write a program that simulates flipping a coin repeatedly and continues until three consecutive heads are tossed, in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "random.h"


using namespace std;

bool FlipCoin(int flip);

int main(){ 

    int flip;
    int heads = 0;
    int total_flips = 0;
    while( heads < 3){
        total_flips++;
        if(FlipCoin(flip) == "heads"){
            heads++;
        } else{
            heads = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "it took " << total_flips << "to get 3 consecutive heads. " << endl;

}   


bool FlipCoin(int flip) {

    if (randomChance(0.50)) {
        return "heads";
    } else {
        return "tails";
    }
}
```

I am getting this error in the main body of my code that states that

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

at the `if (FlipCoin(flip) == "heads")` part. If anyone can help me correct this that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Since strings are inefficient and error-prone (one typo and your comparison fails, while the compiler stays absolutely silent) and bools do not represent coin sides very well (is true heads or tails?), the best way to write this is using an enum:

```
enum class CoinSide { heads, tails };

CoinSide FlipCoin() { // note: you don't need the "flip" parameter
  if (randomChance(0.50)) {
    return CoinSide::heads;
  } else {
    return CoinSide::tails;
  }
}

int main() {
  ...
  if (FlipCoin() == CoinSide::heads) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `FlipCoin()` with a return type of `bool`, but you're returning `char*` from it. You have a couple of options:

1. Change FlipCoin() to return `char*`. Then use `if (strcmp(FlipCoin(flip), "heads") == 0)`. `"heads" == "heads"` works in C/C++, but only because of luck because the compiler optimizes the string table. So the pointers are equal, but it's not exactly correct. `strcmp()` returns 0 if the strings are equal, non-zero if they are not.
2. Change FlipCoin to return `std::string`, then use `if (FlipCoin(flip) == "heads")`.

You should be getting a few compiler warnings from this code, about returning char* from a bool function, and about an unused parameter (flip) being passed into FlipCoin().

Comment: You can use == perfectly satisfactorily to compare C++ strings, and there's no luck involved.  It's also a hell of a lot more readable. Perhaps you were a Java developer in a former life?

Comment: @Poldie - you are correct. I haven't used std::string in a long, long time and was going off the docs on cplusplus.com (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), which requires one more click to find the relational operators. I have edited my answer to reflect the simpler syntax.

Comment: It's there but it's fairly well hidden: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/

Comment: You don't even need the explicit construction. If FlipCoin returns a std::string, then `FlipCoin(flip) == "heads"` will work.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, also correct. Your comment has been edited into the answer. +1 for community.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
bool FlipCoin [....] return "heads";
```

Do you believe that `"heads"` / `"tails"` qualifies as a `boolean` type?

You should decide if `FlipCoin` is going to return `true` / `false`, or return a string.

After you've resolved that, you can fix your if-statement comparison:

```
if(FlipCoin(flip) == "heads"){
```

To either compare against a bool or a string.

But right now, it does not make any sense to declare `FlipCoin` to return a `bool`, actually return a string, try to convert the string to a bool, then try to compare the bool to a string.